# Equivalent div property for row in textarea in html

Tags: css, html, razor, textarea

May I know the equivalent div property for row in textarea?

```
<textarea class="case-notes" rows="5">

<div class="case-notes">
```

Basically I want to show some text in a div so that a user can scroll down. Disabled in textarea removes the scroll down feature.

Comment: Using a small JSFiddle with only `<textarea disabled="disabled" rows="5"></textarea>` containing about 20 lines of whitespace still lets me scroll down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for...

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 100px">Long text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give the `<div>` a height in `em` units which is sort of like the `rows` attribute for a `<div>`, and then set it's `overflow` to `auto` so you can scroll the contents if they are taller than the `<div>`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll">Lots of content here.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.scroll { height:10em; overflow:auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use an empty `<span></span>` to maintain the scroll?